# Sudoku Solver Scilab

Tags: algorithm, runtime-error, sudoku, backtracking, scilab

I am trying to write a program that solves sudoku's using backtracking.
I'm using scilab at the moment.
I keep getting errors in my recursive algorithm, I must be doing something wrong. Any help is welcome.

I put my error code at the bottom.

```
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//////////////////////////   Check Sudoku   ///////////////////////////////
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

function r=OneToNine(V) // function checks if the given vector V contains 1 to 9
r = %T                  // this works
u = %F
index = 1
while r == %T & index < 10
    for i=1 : length(V)
        if V(i)==index then 
            u = %T
        end
    end
    index=index+1
    if u == %F then r = %F
        else u = %F
    end          
end
if length(V) > 9 then r = %F
end
endfunction

function y=check(M) // Checks if the given matrix M is a solved sudoku
y = %T              // this works too

if size(M,1)<>9 | size(M,2)<>9 then // if it has more or less than 9 rows and columns
    y = %F                          // we return false
end

for i=1 : size(M,1)                 // if not all rows have 1-9 we return false
    if OneToNine(M(i,:)) == %F then
        y = %F
    end
end
endfunction


function P=PossibilitiesPosition(board, x, y)
// this one works
// we fill the vector possibilites with 9 zeros
// 0 means empty, 1 means it already has a value, so we don't need to change it

possibilities = []      // a vector that stores the possible values for position(x,y)
for t=1 : 9            // sudoku has 9 values
    possibilities(t)=0
end

// Check row f the value (x,y) for possibilities
// we fill the possibilities further by puttin '1' where the value is not possible 
for i=1 : 9            // sudoku has 9 values
    if board(x,i) > 0 then
        possibilities(board(x,i))=1
    end
end

// Check column of the value (x,y) for possibilities
// we fill the possibilities further by puttin '1' where the value is not possible
for j=1 : 9            // sudoku has 9 values
    if board(j, y) > 0 then
        possibilities(board(j, y))=1
    end
end

// Check the 3x3 matrix of the value (x,y) for possibilities
// first we see which 3x3 matrix we need
k=0
m=0
   if x >= 1 & x <=3 then
       k=1
   else if x >= 4 & x <= 6 then
           k = 4
   else k = 7
       end
   end
   if y >= 1 & y <=3 then
       m=1
   else if y >= 4 & y <= 6 then
           m = 4
   else m = 7
       end
   end

   // then we fill the possibilities further by puttin '1' where the value is not possible
   for i=k : k+2
       for j=m : m+2
           if board(i,j) > 0 then
               possibilities(board(i,j))=1
           end
       end           
   end       
   P = possibilities

   // we want to see the real values of the possibilities. not just 1 and 0
   for i=1 : 9            // sudoku has 9 values
       if P(i)==0 then
           P(i) = i
       else P(i) = 0
       end
   end

endfunction





///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//////////////////////////   Solve Sudoku   ///////////////////////////////
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

function S=solve(board) // the real solving function, here must be a problem somewhere
x=1
y=1
possibilities = [] // an empty vector to put in the possible value later on

if check(board) == %T then // if it's a fully solved sudoku the function gives the solution
    S = board

else
    for i=1 : 9                   // sudoku has 9 values
        for j=1 : 9               // sudoku has 9 values
            if board(i,j)==0 then // if the value board(i,j) is empty so 0
                x=i               // we put the coordinates in x and y
                y=j               // break means stop the loop
                break
            end
        end
    end
    possibilities = PossibilitiesPosition(board,x,y) //we check the possibilities

    for p=1 : 9                             // sudoku has 9 values
        if possibilities(p) > 0 then        // if this is a possibility
            board(x,y) = possibilities(p)   // we put in that value
            solve(board)                    // and we repeat until check(board) gives true
        end
    end
    board(x,y)=0                            // if we went trough al the possibilities
end                                         // and there is still no solution we have to put that value back to 0
                                            // this is called backtracking
endfunction


//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

Error code:

```
// Very Easy sudoku from brainbashers.com

M = [0 2 0 0 0 0 0 4 0
 7 0 4 0 0 0 8 0 2
 0 5 8 4 0 7 1 3 0
 0 0 1 2 8 4 9 0 0
 0 0 0 7 0 5 0 0 0
 0 0 7 9 3 6 5 0 0
 0 8 9 5 0 2 4 6 0
 4 0 2 0 0 0 3 0 9
 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 8 0]

solve(M)
```

!--error 4 
Undefined variable: S
at line      31 of function solve called by :
at line      24 of function solve called by :
at line      24 of function solve called by :
at line      24 of function solve called by :
at line      24 of function solve called by :
at line      24 of function solve called by :
at line      24 of function solve called by :
at line      24 of function solve called by :
at line      24 of function solve called by :
at line      24 of function solve called by :
at line      24 of function solve called by :
at line      24 of function solve called by :
at line      24 of function solve called by :
solve(M)
at line     184 of exec file called by :
B-8525585618758424927.sce', 1
while executing a callback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue is this line:

```
solve(board)
```

which should be

```
S = solve(board)
```

A recursive function must provide two things: a way to delegate a modified task to another instance of itself, *and* a way to return the result to the instance that called it. You didn't have the second thing.

Another, lesser issue, is your search for x,y:

```
for i=1 : 9                   // sudoku has 9 values
    for j=1 : 9               // sudoku has 9 values
        if board(i,j)==0 then // if the value board(i,j) is empty so 0
            x=i               // we put the coordinates in x and y
            y=j               // break means stop the loop
            break
        end
    end
end
```

The `break` command only stops the loop from which it was called. So, it breaks your loop over j, but then the loop over i continues. A quick fix:

```
x=0    // instead of 1
y=0    // instead of 1

// other stuff you have there

for i=1 : 9                   // sudoku has 9 values
    for j=1 : 9               // sudoku has 9 values
        if board(i,j)==0 then // if the value board(i,j) is empty so 0
            x=i               // we put the coordinates in x and y
            y=j               // break means stop the loop
            break
        end
    end
    if x>0 then
        break
    end
end
```

Also, you probably wanted `disp(solve(M))` at the end; otherwise the end result of computation is neither shown nor kept in any variable.

With these corrections, your code does work, outputting this solution:

```
1.    2.    6.    8.    9.    3.    7.    4.    5.  
7.    3.    4.    6.    5.    1.    8.    9.    2.  
9.    5.    8.    4.    2.    7.    1.    3.    6.  
5.    6.    1.    2.    8.    4.    9.    7.    3.  
8.    9.    3.    7.    1.    5.    6.    2.    4.  
2.    4.    7.    9.    3.    6.    5.    1.    8.  
3.    8.    9.    5.    7.    2.    4.    6.    1.  
4.    7.    2.    1.    6.    8.    3.    5.    9.  
6.    1.    5.    3.    4.    9.    2.    8.    7.
```

---

Things to consider:

1. The double loop over i,j should be another function, one that receives a matrix and returns the first (x,y) coordinates where the entry is zero. Then this function would just have `return [i,j]` inside of the double loop, stopping the whole double loop:

```
for i=1 : 9                   // sudoku has 9 values
    for j=1 : 9               // sudoku has 9 values
        if board(i,j)==0 then // if the value board(i,j) is empty so 0
            return [i,j]
        end
    end
end
// do something if the matrix is full
```

2. The backtracking is not implemented correctly. The command `board(x,y)=0` has no effect, since the value of local variable `board` is simply forgotten when the function ends. Your code would go into infinite recursion if given an unsolvable puzzle.